# Parameter Validation Best Practices

Tags: c#, validation, parameter-passing

Imagine you have an application which is some kind of *front-end* to all your business logic. This front-end has a lot of DLLs upon which it depends, and the methods in those DLLs may call each other repeatedly upon a single execution of a given method in the front-end. If the users of your application do not directly access those DLLs, should you...

1) Risk a (small) performance hit and validate parameters in each of those methods, even if you can end up validating the same parameters some 5 times; or

2) Risk unexpected behaviour and assume that, as you validate input parameters, all the other possible parameters passed to and from your internal code are valid (for example, neither null nor empty)?

**Edit:** Just to give an example, suppose you have a Regex `RegexA` and a method

```
internal bool Matches(string expression)
{
    return RegexA.IsMatch(expression);
}
```

`IsMatch` will throw an exception on a null parameter, but not on the empty string. If you know  beforehand that an empty string will never be a match to that Regex, should  you use `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(expression))` before, even knowing that it may be validated for nullity inside the `IsMatch` framework method? In this case you are clearly repeating a validation, but is it better to repeat it or to risk?

Comment: i do not get what you mean by "even if you can end up validating the same parameters some 5 times"

Comment: @Bumble Bee: He means that as your program execution travels down the stack, there may be a dozen methods that check that the `value != null`. So the same logic is performed multiple times on the same value, as opposed to not being checked at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Usually parameter checks are very **cheap**, even if called thousands of times.
For example test if a value is null, a string or Collection is emtpy a number is in a given range.

But beware that checks may be **expensive**, so think twice: Evaluating a regex on a large string, checking if a file exists, checking that *all* elements in a collection meets a certain criteria.

I would also only recommend checking only in **public or protected** methods.
Note that all public methods with unchecked parameters are **potential risks**!

**EDIT/another thought:**
If a method does not use the parameters but is **just passing** it to another method then you may also omit the checking. Only the method which is **actually using** these parameters for itself should do the checking.

This is because if the requirements of the parameters change you need to change the validations in multiple places, risking **inconsistency**.

Comment: +1. Regarding your edit, by deferring validation until the parameter is actually used, you may be making it more difficult to catch bugs. What if the parameter is always provided, but is only used under certain rare circumstances? If one of the calling methods provides an invalid value, I would want to know this immediately, even if the value might not be used this time through the method. It should be possible to consolidate a particular argument's validation code to prevent repetition and inconsistency, while still validating the argument as soon as possible (and as often as necessary).

Comment: @StriplingWarrior However if I know that this parameter will not be used I can pass in any value (null/empty string) just as a filler. This is a bad design though, imo, and there should be a method overload for that (if language allows).

Answer (score 13):

Unless the validation of the parameter is going to be expensive, I would go with #1. Fail-fast behavior lets you catch bugs in a fraction of the time, which will save you a lot more time than it takes to write a few guard statements at the beginning of each method.

One technology you may be interested to help with this is .NET's Code Contracts, which allow you to create quasi-compile-time checks to ensure that nobody calls a method without ensuring that the inputs match the expected patterns.

I personally tried using Code Contracts, and found that there was a little too much overhead for my needs. However, I appreciated the syntax, so I made a class to help with these guard statements, but which only works at run-time. It works like this:

```
public void ChangeUserName(int userId, string name)
{
    Require.ThatArgument(userId > 0);
    Require.ThatArgument(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(name,
        () => "Usernames must be non-empty strings");
    var user = GetUser(userId);
    Require.That(user != null, 
        () => new UserDoesNotExistException("No user exists with ID " + userId));
    user.Name = name;
    ...
}
```

And one final technology that helps a lot for these checks is Resharper's Annotations. For example, consider the following method:

```
[CanBeNull]
public User GetUser(int userId)
{
    var user =  ... // Get the user from the db
    return user;
}
```

By telling Resharper that the method might return a null value, it will know to warn you if you haven't done a null check on `user` before trying to access `user.Name`. Another annotation is available to tell Resharper that `Require.That(user != null)` constitutes a null check. You could also re-write your method like this:

```
[NotNull]
public User GetUser(int userId)
{
    Require.ThatArgument(userId > 0);
    var user =  ... // Get the user from the db
    Require.That(user != null)
    return user;
}
```

By marking this method as NotNull, Resharper can automatically tell you that `user != null` will always resolve to `true` so you don't have to check for it. There are all kinds of fun stuff you can do to make validation easier.

Answer (score 7):

As an author of a library, you cannot assume that the consumers have done proper validation of inputs, so you as a library author would want to ensure the arguments are valid before going to work with them.

As a consumer of a library, if you know what inputs are going to cause the library to fail, why would you pass those inputs to that library? Validate against them so that you can perhaps prompt your user for better inputs or otherwise cancel whatever process you are in.

The fact that you might be the author of both the library and the consumer is not particularly relevant, in my opinion, as this relationship may very well change.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting topic :)

in general you should implement a "validation facade" lower than the user interface and at the lowest possible level commonly accessed by user interface and external services.

you can check for null and validate input also in the UI just to avoid a useless round-trip to the server, client side validation is a good practice, still you cannot trust the caller to only pass you valid values.

Answer (score 1):

You may get mixed opinions, but in my view..it is best to do validation in both the layers. In the front and the business logic (dlls as you call it)