# Validate Parameters at compile-time?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a simple function:

```
public static int NewNumber(int lowestValue, int highiestValue) {}
```

I would like to have some a compiler check if parameters are correct. For example, in this case, the developer could mistakenly (or on purpose) call the method like this:

```
NewNumber(5, -5);
```

which is wrong in this case - The developer lied.

Sure I could make a simple check inside the method:

```
 public static int NewNumber(int lowestValue, int highiestValue) {
       if (highiestValue <= lowestValue) {
           //Error
       }
   }
```

...  and it would work just perfectly. However, I'm curious if there is anything the developer can do in this case to restrict such behavior without additional checking in the method itself.

**EDIT: Found out the solution but nonrelated to the C#**

Since I'm working in Unity I end up with writing custom inspector so values can be entered correctly in the Unity Inspector itself, thus eliminating unnecessary checks (and slowing the performance) when calling the method many times per second.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510171/parameter-validation-best-practices#6510222

Comment: `The developer lied` lol

Comment: You can't really stop developers from lying.  We're just so good at it.

Comment: The compiler is supposed to interpret the meaning of a variable name now?

Comment: @LarsTech Why not? If the function is called 40,50,60 or more times per second all variable checks are completely unnecessary if the parameter value never changes. Why would you lose precious CPU time if this could be handled differently? And I'm not talking about simple checks that are in the case above.

Comment: Thank you for noticing, but you still didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This I don't believe is possible. Consider this situation,

```
NewNumber(x, y);
```

What's `x` and `y`? The compiler doesn't necessarily know what the input is (e.g. `x = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`).

You gave hard-coded examples, and perhaps you might only use the function with hard-coded values, but the compiler only knows that `5` and `-5` are integers and integers can be a literal `5, -5, etc` or a variable `var a = 5;`

Comment: True.

However, I'm still learning and I thought maybe it could be done while passing the parameters to the method using  "where" keyword or something (like when using generics for passing the correct data type).

Maybe this was a dumb question in the first place but it was worth trying. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, some people forget they were a beginner once too. I think it's great your questioning ways of doing things instead of taking other people's code at face-value. It's probably best to just throw an exception if high is less than low in this case though. Simplest to follow for other people reading your code too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a compiler related parameter argument check.  But it is always better to have your parameter check within your method (responsibility of your method to take care the parameter) and document it better so, the caller knows what data it should pass to your method.